# Add all Arrays with an Main Array without duplicates

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I need to add an array of array in to a single array without duplicates

```
array = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]]
```

to

```
new_array [1,2,3,4,7,8,9]
```

What is the best possible way to do IT in Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
array.flatten!.uniq!
```

[`flatten!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) takes any sub-arrays and adds their elements to the enclosing array (recursively), so it "flattens out" arrays of arrays.

[`uniq!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) removes duplicate elements from the array.

Note that ! methods modify the original array. Use the non-! methods ([`flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq)) if you wish to return a new array instead.