# Better alternative to join() and split() in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, join

I have an array of arrays of Strings.

It looks like this:

```
big_array = Array.new
big_array[0] = ["aib","ulster","anglo","hsbc"]
big_array[1] = ["ulster","hdfc","citibank"]
big_array[2] = ["aib", "citibank"]
```

Now, from this, I want to create another array with the names of the banks. 
The only way I know how to do this is.

```
big_array.join(" ").split(" ").uniq
```

Now, this works for small amounts of data. But what if big_array's indexes run up to 1000s. Doesn't seem like the best way to do this. Is there a better way to implement this?

P.S. I've just given an example for what I'm trying to do. Not the actual code. Just want a more elegant solution.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26389508/477037) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317653/how-can-i-more-elegantly-remove-duplicate-items-across-all-elements-of-a-ruby-ar). Is this a contest?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370142/can-i-make-this-ruby-code-faster-and-or-use-less-memory) is another one.

Comment: @Stefan takes an early lead by identifying three similiar questions, but Cary is quickly closing, have added [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739271/ruby-new-unique-array-of-nested-array-items) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005055/add-all-arrays-with-an-main-array-without-duplicates) in quick succession...

Comment: looks like most of my class tried to get their solution from here.. In my defense, i'd already submitted the assignment before asking here. Was just curious as to what could be a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and please don't be put off by my attempt at levity at your expense. You'll get the hang of it soon enough. When you have time, have a look at this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
big_array = Array.new
big_array[0] = ["aib","ulster","anglo","hsbc"]
big_array[1] = ["ulster","hdfc","citibank"]
big_array[2] = ["aib", "citibank"]
big_array.flatten.uniq
# => ["aib", "ulster", "anglo", "hsbc", "hdfc", "citibank"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more concisely:

```
big_array = []
big_array << ["aib","ulster","anglo","hsbc"]
big_array << ["ulster","hdfc","citibank"]
big_array << ["aib", "citibank"]
big_array.flatten.uniq
```